# Statistical Test involving the Mean and variance of two samples

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am doing a hypothesis test two see if two sets X and Y both containing 100 values are both part of a parent set, or are two unique sets.

So H0:X and Y are belong to the same parent set
   H1:They are from two different set

I decided to use a 5% significance level

To check this I used a statistical test using the difference in their means, and this result led me to reject H0.
I then used a statistical test using the difference in their variance, and this result led me to accept H0.

Is there a statistical test I could you use that could detect a differnce in the mean and variances?

Comment: You say you used the difference in their means twice. Should one of those say 'variance' instead, or are they different tests?

Comment: yes sorry one should say variance